# Wordpress Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, amp-html, multisite

I have my main site, for example, xample.com, now I have another site m.xample.com(For mobile).
both are Wordpress sites and one is the main site and another is a mobile site for main site,
how can I stop the subdomain from being indexed on google and stop people from opening the m.xample.com(Mobile site subdomain) on PC,
I want that, When people try to open m.xample.com on mobile it should work, but if they try to open it on PC it should redirect to xamnple.com(Main site), and even don't want it indexed.

Answer (score 0):

- You can remove the sub-domain through google search console.
- You can prevent robots from crawling the sub-domain editing the
  `robots.txt`.
- You can add `noindex` to the mobile pages. (added to your `header`
  file so it can cover all pages)